# Umbraco 10 - MapControllerRoute and RenderController

Tags: routes, umbraco

I'm creating an Umbraco 10 site and trying to add routing for a RenderController. But I keep on getting a 404, page not found error, when I try the route's URL.

Inside startup.cs I have the following code:

```
             .WithEndpoints(u =>
             {
                u.EndpointRouteBuilder.MapControllerRoute(
                   name: "Article-List",
                   pattern: "/NewsArticle/Show/{category}",
                   new { Controller = "NewsArticle", Action = "Show"}
                   ); 
                // Normal Umbraco endpoints
              });
```

and the render controller has the following code:

```
   public class NewsArticleController : RenderController
   {
      private readonly IUmbracoContextAccessor _umbracoContextAccessor;
      private readonly UmbracoHelper _umbracoHelper;

      public NewsArticleController(ILogger<RenderController> logger, ICompositeViewEngine compositeViewEngine, IUmbracoContextAccessor umbracoContextAccessor, UmbracoHelper umbracoHelper)
        : base(logger, compositeViewEngine, umbracoContextAccessor)
      {
         _umbracoContextAccessor = umbracoContextAccessor;
         _umbracoHelper = umbracoHelper;
      }

      [HttpGet]
      [Route("/NewsArticle/Show/{category}")]
      public IActionResult Show(String category)
      {
            return Content("Hello world - looking for" + category);
      }
}
```

Trying this URL https://localhost:44381/NewsArticle/Show/financials results in a 404 page not found error.

PS - I'm using Visual Studio 2022 community.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure exactly what you're trying to achieve: a custom controller (outside the Umbraco pipeline and routing) or a standard view controller (inside the Umbraco pipeline and routing). When talking about controllers inside Umbraco's pipeline there are a number of variants: render, surface, api, hijacked. The render variant is for returning plain old views, which is what it looks like you want.

**For standard controllers**

See: https://docs.umbraco.com/umbraco-cms/v/10.latest-lts/implementation/default-routing/controller-selection (Default Controller Action).

The routing should be something like  https://localhost:44381/NewsArticle/ or https://localhost:44381/NewsArticle/index for the default page, which is more or less what you have.

I'd get that working for the Index (default) page then add the additional endpoint for Show: https://localhost:44381/NewsArticle/Show. Note I wouldn't expect to have to use the `[Route()]` attribute for that.

**For more complex Controllers**

The usage of WithEndpoints and in startup.cs indicates to me that you may want Custom routing.

If you want custom routing, or something outside of Umbraco, see
https://docs.umbraco.com/umbraco-cms/v/10.latest-lts/reference/routing/custom-routes.

Note your example doesn't seem to quite match up with the code in https://docs.umbraco.com/umbraco-cms/v/10.latest-lts/reference/routing/custom-routes#where-to-put-your-routing-logic in terms of where the /*/ Normal Umbraco endpoints* should go. You may need to rejig the order to get that working.

Comment: Anthony, thanks. I was just going to mark this as solved. 

I found the link you shared and it helped.  (I used the "IVirtualPageController" solution as a guide. https://docs.umbraco.com/umbraco-cms/reference/routing/custom-routes#custom-route-with-ivirtualpagecontroller) 

I needed to change my controller so it inherited from UmbracoPageController and IVirtualPageController. then add the FindContent() method to my class.